# Viewing unencrypted VPN Traffic with Wireshark

Tags: vpn, wireshark

Long story short I'm testing something and trying to figure out how to view VPN data (the default server/client setup through Windows) using Wireshark. In my test environment I've got Wireshark running on both the server and the client but I only see PPTP traffic.

I've got all credential information for the VPN (obviously) but I haven't found any way to view the decrypted traffic. I found a link that said it couldn't be done on Windows 7 but I'm running XP atm.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Maybe try it on a networking forum?

Comment: I'd suggest asking this question over on superuser or serverfault.

Comment: Alright, if this isn't the right place can I mod move it or should I just repost?

Comment: This is probably a Wireshark-specific issue (and probably doesn't depend on whether you're running Wireshark on XP or W7, but might depend on the OS doing the VPN traffic), and would probably be best asked on [the Wireshark Q&A site](http://ask.wireshark.org).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this question on the Wireshark Q&A so for anyone who has this problem in the future I solved it by install Netmon on both boxes. After that the VPN interface was available for Wireshark to sniff.